# Set parent element to property of current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of elements which have parents that need an attribute from the child (only child).

```
var elements = $("img");
elements.parent().attr("href", $(this).attr('src'));
```

This code does not work. What I am trying to do is set the parent src attribute using the src value from the calling child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate and set:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var imgSrc = this.src;
    $(this).parent().attr("href", imgSrc);
});
```